# How to simulate LEFT JOIN as INNER JOIN in SQL Server while creating indexed view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view, indexed-view

It is possible to simulate left join using inner join while creating indexed view in SQL Server? I found a solution using `ISNULL(id,0)` but it does not work for me.

I have `Table1 (ID PK, ID_U FK null)` and I want to left join `Table2 (ID_U PK, VALUE)`. I want to see all rows from `Table1` and associated rows from `Table2` if exist ID_U.

In created view script I have

```
select t1.ID, t1.ID_U, t2.VALUE 
from Table1 t1 
join Table2 t2 on t1.ID_U = t2.ID_U 
               or (ISNULL(t1.ID_U, 0) = 0 and ISNULL(t2.ID_U, 0) = 0)
where t1.ID_U is null -- only for test

/* create clustered index */
```

As a result I should see all rows from `Table1` where ID_U is null with nulls in right table, but I have 0 rows.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any reason for not using the left join ?

Comment: Why do you think this would work? A left-join cannot be simulated with an inner, only the other way round. Your only options are: just making two separate views, one joined and one not and unioning them at runtime. Or use an actual dummy value 0 instead of null.

Comment: @iDevlop A left-join cannot be used in an indexed view.

Comment: @iDevlop I cannot use outer joins on indexed views include left, right... only inner join is possible when i want to create index on that view.

Comment: @Charlieface "Or use an actual dummy value 0 instead of null. " Can you explain?

Comment: Trying to simulate a `LEFT JOIN` with an `INNER JOIN` doesn't get around that limitation, @blane . This is most certainly an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Why do you think you need an index on the view? Often this is the wrong solution to a different problem.

Comment: Indexed views are physically saved on disk, as far as I know, which is why they are faster than non-indexed views.

Comment: better use the view as it is and then come back if you have some perf issues. a simple LEFT JOIN shouldn't be much improved by indexed views unless your indexes are bad

Comment: I want to create a view because I want to use ODATA to use paginate, filter and sort. But maybe it is possible to create such a 'view' from several tables using Odata from the C# side?

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend you do this.

You really should not do this.

Not even sure if SQL will allow you to create an indexed view doing this - hope not.

But, if you absolutely have to make an INNER act like a LEFT JOIN, then here's one way...

```
select 
    t1.ID, 
    t1.ID_U, 
    iif(t1.ID_U IS NULL, NULL, t2.Value) as Value  -- return NULL when joined with the dummy record
from Table1 t1 
join Table2 t2 on t1.ID_U = t2.ID_U 
               or ISNULL(t1.ID_U, 1) = t2.ID_U  -- this joins the same row from t2 (with ID_U = 1) to every row in t1 that has a ID_U of NULL .  NOTE:  There must be a row in t2 with ID_U = 1
```